# How to get height of the highest element in the div and set this height to the div?

Tags: jquery

I wrote small news ticker - http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/SvFRs/

Problem which I have is that - there is content straigt after news div and I need to know the height of the heighest element in that div (and set this height to the div(parent) ), so I would avoid movement of element underneath it.

Please see my example - http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/SvFRs/

Any help much appreciated.

Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NqGL9/

i made the background gray to see if it works

Comment: And, once we have that working - how do I make auto scroll + pause on hover?

Comment: @Pete: If you've got more problems to resolve, post them as new questions rather than tagging them on to the comments of an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the max height using

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $(".notice").map(
  function(){
    return $(this).height();
  }
));
```

And set it to the div

```
$(".noticeboard").height(max);
```

Comment: this looks good but i get this error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type