# get the highest div from main div jquery

Tags: jquery, height, each

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507446/how-to-get-height-of-the-highest-element-in-the-div-and-set-this-height-to-the-di) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076231/how-to-get-height-of-the-highest-children-element-in-javascript-jquery) as well, but I just can't get them to work.

I have a main div with many children with different ids and classes inside it.
I need to find a way the get the heights of a certain class and set the next divs' heights according to them.
I know it's not working but it may help you understand what I would like to achieve:

```
var placesHeight = 0;
$('.places').each(function(){
    if(height > 35 ) {
    $(this).next('.nextdiv').css('height','(placesHeight+25)+"px"');
});
```

EDIT: Thanks for the quick help everyone. I tried all of it and realized all I need is this:

```
var placesHeight = $('.places').height();
$('.nextdiv').css('height', placesHeight+25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
.css('height','(placesHeight+25)+"px"');
```

The value of placesHeight won't be parsed - it's going to try to set the value of the height as `(placesHeight+25)+"px"`.  It can be done more simply:

```
.css('height', placesHeight+25);
```

The "px" will be added automatically for you.

Comment: why not just use `.height('yourheight')` instead ?

Comment: I tried to mimic the code and fix the "broken" bit - I honestly couldn't follow the intent of the code.  My hope is that a simple fix of the syntax problem allows @elbatron to find the semantic solution needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var placesHeight = 0;
$('.places').each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 35 ) {
    $(this).next('.nextdiv').css('height',$(this).height()+25+"px");
});
```

something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
$(this).next('.nextdiv').height(placesHeight+25);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see more of your markup - a jsfiddle would be best.  Something like this might work though:

```
$('.places').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        height = $(this).height();
    height > 35 && $this.next().height(height);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps somehow,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function test(){
    $("#my_div").children('.check_me').each(function(){
        alert( $(this).outerHeight());
    });
}
</script>
<style>
#my_div div{
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
    border:1pt solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<button onclick='test()'>try me</button>

<div id='my_div'>
    <div id='one_line' class='check_me'>
        first
    </div>
    <div id='two_lines'>
        first<br>second
    </div>
    <div id='three lines' class='check_me'>
        first<br>second<br>third
    </div>
<div>
```